# Clojure change values of a map without changing the order

Tags: dictionary, clojure, ref

I have given a map which looks like this:

```
{:foo 121 :yo 85 :good 85 :nice 53 :better 35 :cheaper 26 :price 26 }
```

Well I want to do some mathematics on the value of the map but without changing the order of the map. 
For example if I have a total-count of 400 then I want the new map should look like:

```
{:foo 121/400 :yo 85/400 :good 85/400 :nice 53/400 :better 35/400 :cheaper 26/400 :price 26/400 }
```

I can do it with reduce but it is changing the order of the map. I think I have to use ref and alter to do this but any solution with ref I was working on did failed.

How to solve this?

Comment: If you need an order then you picked a wrong datatype. Hashmaps don't sustain order of elements. It's a trade-off to provide `O(1)` look-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a map that keeps the insertion order like [ordered](https://github.com/flatland/ordered).

You could in theory also use an array-map, but they auto promote to hash-maps which would be a headache to use if you are going to manipulate them.

Comment: Ah ok that mapping really helps :D

Answer (score 1):

When operating on a clojure map in a polymorphic way it's not guaranteed that order of elements will be preserved. So if your collection is not too large you probably could use [array-map](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/array-map). But array-map becomes hash-map after certain number of insertations (if nothing was changed this number is 10)

Also you might like this ordered map implementation https://github.com/flatland/ordered